# How can I switch between unstaged changes and old code?

Tags: git

Is there a quick way to switch between the code before the recent (unstaged) changes and the current code ?

My use case is seeing how the app behaves differently before and after my changes on a specific page.

So far I have used two different approaches

1. Switch between `master` and my current working branch
2. use `git stash` and `git stash apply` to remove and re apply the unstaged changes

The first approach is a bit slow and sometimes master is behind my main branch by a few other commits so it's not really great for comparison.

The second one seems to me like the preferred way but I am getting the impression people use this command more to put away recent changes, go work on another branch and then go back on whatever they are working on.

I was wondering if there is another preferred way or if this is it.

Comment: `git stash pop` instead of `git stash apply` so your stash doesn’t keep growing, but yeah, `git stash` is perfect for what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stash does the job what difference does it make how others use it or what they do during the stash?

Here's my routine:

```
git add .; git stash
```

Later...

```
git stash pop
```

Pop removes the stash from the file. Use `apply` if you want it saved for posterity.

Comment: Well it's always useful to validate that this is the proper way of doing things. You never know if there are side effects or easier ways to do it. In this case I learned about `git stash pop`.